# Why is $\mathbb{Z}\to \{\frac{n}{m}: n \in \mathbb{Z}\}, n\mapsto \frac{n}{m}$ bijective with $m,n \in \mathbb{Z}$?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

> Why is $\mathbb{Z}\to \{\frac{n}{m}: n \in \mathbb{Z}\}, n\mapsto \frac{n}{m}$ bijective with $m,n \in \mathbb{Z}$?

So I realized this is a function with $\mathbb{Z}$ as domain and $ \{\frac{n}{m}: n \in \mathbb{Z}\}$ as codomain. How would this function even graphically look like? Wouldn't that just be a linear function? How do you deduce it's a bijective function?

Comment: I guess $m \in \mathbb{Z} \smallsetminus\{0\}$, otherwise I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: Bear in mind that $m$ is a *constant*.  This is *not* a bijection from $\mathbb Z$ to $\mathbb Q$ but a bijection to $\{....,\frac {-2}m, \frac{-1}m, 0 , \frac 1m, \frac 2m, \frac 3m,.....\}$.  If you realize that and realize that $\frac 1m$ is just a constant $a$ this is just a bijection for $\{z|z\in \mathbb Z\}$ to $\{az|z\in \mathbb Z\}$.  Hopefully how to show that should be familiar.

Answer (score 0):

It is indeed a linear function. You could say that $f(n) = \frac1m \cdot n$.

To show that it is bijective, you would need to show that it is both injective and surjective.
For injectivity, show that whenever $f(n_1)=f(n_2)$ we have $n_1 = n_2$.
For surjectivity, show that whenever $y\in \{\frac n m : n\in \Bbb Z\}$ there is some $n\in \Bbb Z$ with $f(n) = y$.

I suppose one important piece of information you might be overlooking is that $m$ is assumed to be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

This represents a whole family of functions, one for each (nonzero) $m$.  It takes integers to fractions with denominator $m$.  For example, if $m=3$ we have $f(1)=\frac 13, f(7)=\frac 73, f(-10)=-\frac {10}3$ and so on.  If you plot my example you will have a series of dots, one at each integer, located at $(n,\frac n3)$

To show it is a bijection, note that given $n$ you can always find a unique $\frac nm$ and given $\frac nm$ in the image you can always find a unique $n$, so we have injections both ways.

Answer (score 0):

You are assuming that $m$ is fixed so the codomain is all rational numbers with the denominator equal to $m$.

Note that $$\frac {n_1}{m}=\frac {n_2}{m}\implies n_1=n_2$$

Thus your function is one-to-one.

Also if $\frac {n}{m}$ is a member of the codomain then $f(n)=\frac {n}{m}$ thus your function is onto.

Therefore your function is bijective.